# Is there possible to edit string using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I want to edit string like below example :

```
$str = '$variable$123'
```

Convert to

```
$str = '$variable$*123'
```

I tried below code :

```
<?php

$str = '$variable$123';
$str= preg_replace('/(\$\w*\$.[0-9]*)+/i', '$1*$2', $str);
echo $str;

?>
```

But didn't get as i want...

Please help.....

Comment: Are you always going to have only two $s in your string?

Comment: ya... more example string like  `$a1$123+($a3$)` , `$b1$$xyz$` , `$c1$123$c2$`..

Comment: Maybe [this](http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3?s=$variable$123&-17&1&-18&-4) can help you?

Comment: So no, you won't have :)

Comment: You need two capturing groups (pairs of unescaped parentheses) if you are going to use two replacement tokens (`$1` and `$2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
<?

$str1 = '$variable$123$variable2$';    
echo replace($str1);

$str2 = '$variable$123';
echo replace($str2);

function replace($str)
{
    $str = preg_replace('/(\$\w*\$)(\d+)/i', '$1*$2', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(\d+)(\$\w*\$)/i', '$1*$2', $str);        
    return $str
}

?>
```

**output** :

`$variable$*123*$variable2$`

`$variable$*123`

Comment: @ring0 Sorry... i failed to explain question properly... :( but your ans partially correct... so i give + point but not accept ans..

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\$\w+\$)(\d+)/', '$1*$2', $str);
```

Another (simpler) version that may fit the exemple given in comment

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\$\w+\$)/', '$1*', $str);
```

Comment: You never specified what was supposed to happen with more than 2 dollar signs.

Comment: Not like that but if string like `$c1$123$c2$444` then i want to output string like `$c1$*123*$c2$*444`